# Line draw next to mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I'm trying to make an app to edit images. I've struggled with saving my graphics drawn on an image for a while and I've got that fixed now, but my next problem is that the lines now appear a few pixels away from the mouse position.

I have this:

```
bool draw = false;
Graphics g;
int? preX = null;
int? preY = null;

private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp; *.png;)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp; *.png;";

    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (draw)
    {    
        Pen pen = new Pen(btnColor.ForeColor, float.Parse(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString()));
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
        g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(preX ?? e.X, preY ?? e.Y), new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        preX = e.X;
        preY = e.Y;
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

I hope this makes sense, otherwise I will try to make things clearer. I don't really understand why this happens but when i start drawing on the picturebox the line doesn't appear at the mouse pointer, but a few pixels to the right. pls help :(

Comment: I have tried your code and everything is just fine the line is at the tip of the arrow, the code that you have posted hire is ok.

Comment: This can only work correctly if you set the picture box' SizeMode property to "Normal".  If it is not then the mouse position no longer matches a pixel position since the image was rescaled.

Comment: that's weird. do you have any idea what it could be then? maybe the size of my picturebox is to small??

Comment: If the position is Always five pixels to the right, you could just fix the difference in the event: `preX = (e.X-5);`

Comment: If you still have an issue, maybe checking the cursor shapes will help. Some point to the upper left some to the middle..